# Incompatibility between TikZ and babel

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, babel

In my preamble, you'll find:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[mathrmOrig]{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{arcs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[scale=0]{background}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{CJKspace}
\usepackage{CJKpunct}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgheros,tgtermes,tgcursor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wboiboites}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox,empheq}
\usepackage[default]{gillius}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[total={18.59cm,26.5cm},left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows, positioning,shadows,shadings,backgrounds,calc, shapes, tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,fadings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings,theorems}
```

I'm trying to draw an arrow for `X axis` and `Y axis`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow!10, fill=blue!5](-1, -1) rectangle (7, 5);
\draw[dotted] (-0.75,-0.75) grid (6.75,4.75);
\node[below] at (-0.25,0){$O$};
\draw[->,black, thick] (-0.75,0)--(6.75,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Additionally, if I remove -> from the options of `\draw` the tikz picture compiles normally.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Particularly important is showing what language(s) you're loading with `babel`. Have you tried adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`? Spanish, I guess.

Comment: I didn't have that command `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. I was compiling with this code before (but on beamer) and now switched to LaTeX, it appeared. Strange

Comment: What do you mean by `on beamer`? Beamer is a special LaTeX class.

Comment: Please reduce your preamble to the packages needed to reproduce the error. Also, I would recommend eliminating packages you do not need and replacing deprecated ones. (`times` is deprecated. You do not need all of the font packages you are using e.g. `lmodern`, `times`, `tgheros`, `tgtermes`, `tgcursor`, `gillius`. These are just overwriting each others' settings.)

Comment: @cfr I'm making a book, so in other parts of it I use those other packages. And about those deprecated, this is the first time I heard about that term.
@Christian Hupfer I used those packages `on Beamer` and worked, but now I switched to `LaTeX` and they gave me some errors. Actually was by the absence of `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: You cannot be using all of those font packages because most of them simply overwrite the settings of the others. So the ones you load last will be in effect for your entire document.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to

1. load `tikz` after `babel`
2. load `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz}`
3. (optional, but recommended) prune off several packages from your preamble, leaving only what's really necessary for your document

Note that the `arcs` package has very severe bugs.

Comment: I loaded them this way: first `\usepackage{tikz}` and then `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` and worked fine for me. Additionally, `arcs` isn't in use right now. I keeped by mistake, because I have another way to create arcs.